# AWS DynamoDB Scan Filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following item in my DynamoDB table -

```
{
    "bannerCarouselId": "testUser1",
    "obj1": {
        "updatedBy": "testUser1"
    },
    "obj2": [{
        "message": "some message here"
    }]
}
```

In some of the items I have a **createdBy** map inside the **obj1** object,
 
example -

```
{
    "bannerCarouselId": "testUser1",
    "obj1": {
        "updatedBy": "testUser1",
        "createdBy": "testUser1"
    },
    "obj2": [{
        "message": "some message here"
    }]
}
```

I am trying to **Scan the table and find the items that do not have a createdBy key inside the obj1 object** from Console, but I am not able to,
[image]